# How to print carriage return in unicode representation in python?

Tags: python, unicode

I use python 2.7, in the following test

```
print repr(u'中')
print repr(u'Œ')
print repr(u'Ȧ')
print repr(u'\r')
print repr(u'1')
```

I got results

```
u'\u4e2d'
u'\u0152'
u'\u0226'
u'\r'
u'1'
```

Some starts with an `\u` but some doesn't.

How do I print `\r` as `\u000D`? or `'1'` as `\u0031`?

Comment: You are printing representations. Python picks how that is displayed, not you, and since `\u000D` is more commonly expressed as `\r` Python picks that representation. The same would apply to newlines (`\n`) and tabs (`\t`), while codepoints past the ASCII range but within the Latin-1 range use `\xhh`. Why do you need this?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for explanation, I just wonder why `\r` doesn't represent as `\u000D`, and it's not a real life project problem.

Comment: Because `\r` is more readily recognisable, it is one of the [7 possible 1-letter escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) Python literals support.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks for the document, I'm reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the ordinal of the character, or its position in the character table. This is returned by 'ord'. For more information please see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord and https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Carriage return is 13 (please see: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/carriage-return-ascii-code-13.html ) by `ord(u'\r')` (or 0xD in hex)

And '中' is 20013 (please see: http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=4E2D) by `ord(u'中')`

If you want it expressed in hexadecimal you could do something like `'%04X' % ord(u'中')` which will return `4E2D`.

Hope this helps.